# Laravel Can't Access other Routes but the Root (with XAMPP)

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xampp

I have just started using Laravel (v5.7) and I am trying to set it up to work in a virtual host (I'm using the XAMPP package for Windows).

To simplify, the only `Route` that works is the `get('/', ...)`. Other routes, like `get('/other', ...)` fails with **Error 404**.  The other routes are only accessable when running the `php artisan serve` server, so I can use port 8000.

However, I wish Apache was handling the requests, without the need of idenifying the port. Is that simple?

A very straight forward code that I'm using and isn't working follows (without controllers):

```
// ROUTE in routes/web.php
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('home');
});
Route::get('/other', function() {
    return view('other');
});
```

NOTE: I do have both view files `home.blade.php` and `other.blade.php` in `resources/views` directory.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP can't make very *clean* URLs.
You have to point your routes to the public folder, not the application root.
So instead of `localhost/MyProject/other`
Try `localhost/MyProject/public/other`

Answer (score 0):

When you change route file you should run this artisan command `php artisan route:cache` that clear route cache.

Can you try my it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error you can try using php artisan serve it solved the issue

Or you can try setting up the host in the following files 
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts